# nil v/s empty in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
if(!@stores.nil?) then
          logger.info ("Storing in recent search")
          logger.info(@stores.nil?)
          logger.info(@stores.empty?)
          logger.info(@stores)
          recentsearch = Recentsearch.create({:query => ss, :type=>tt, :ts=>Time.now})
          recentsearch.save
 end
```

So, if `@stores` is `nil`, the `if-end` should not execute. But strangely (for me) it does. In logs, I see the following :

```
Storing in recent search
nil
true
[]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: I'm surprised by the `nil` in the logs -- `nil.nil?` returns `true`, everything else returns `false`. So where'd `nil` come from?

Comment: Just a tip, in ruby that first line would generally be written `unless @stores.nil?`, and if I know that some kind of list is being passing around I tend to use `unless @stores.nil? || @stores.empty?` as it handles the two "null" cases of a list.

Comment: Note that ActiveSupport's `Object#blank?` and `Object#present?` will work in both cases. They behave more like PHP's `empty()`, which is a combined `nil?` and `empty?` check.

Comment: The only confusing thing I see here is that @stores.nil? is logged as `nil`. Your if is working as expected since @stores = []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `@stores` is not `nil` but initialized to an empty array `[]`.

So `!@stores.nil?` is true because `@stores.nil?` is false. I'm not familiar with `logger.info` so I'm not sure why it prints `nil` for the third line. `empty?` returns true if there is no element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the first line says: `if !@stores.nil?` - if the stores is not nil.

Therefore, the line `@stores.nil?` must not evaluate to true. Indeed, it does not, it shows `nil`, which is (more-less) `false`. Meaning that `@stores` is not nil. The array is empty, but it is present, so everything seems ok.

`nil` signifies no object. Empty array is still an object.